# Typescript: How to change Class Fields Value by Class Function?

Tags: typescript, class

```
    class foo {
      data = {};
      show = true;
      cancel = {
        click: function (data?: any) {
          console.log("click cancel", data);
          this.show = false// todo, When i call "myfoo.cancel.click()", how can i change foo.show to false? If not pass myfoo into click() would be better.
        },
      };
    }

    let myfoo = new foo();
    console.log(myfoo.show);
    myfoo.cancel.click();
    console.log(myfoo.show);
```

output:

```
true
click cancel undefined
true
```

When i call `myfoo.cancel.click()`, how can i change foo.show to `false`?  I hope the output can be:

```
true
click cancel undefined
false
```

By the way, after I read [How to access the correct `this` inside a callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback/20279485#20279485), I know should not use `this`.

If not pass `myfoo` into `cancel.click()` would be better.
The click function used in many popup components,  all the components's cancel button call `cancel.click()`, so I would not write more for `cancel.click()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `click` function to an arrow function:

```
class foo {
  data = {};
  show = true;
  cancel = {
    click: (data?: any) => {
      console.log("click cancel", data);
      this.show = false
    },
  };
}

let myfoo = new foo();
console.log(myfoo.show);
myfoo.cancel.click();
console.log(myfoo.show);
```